# Computer shutdown running command 'dpkg --configure -a'

Tags: package-management, dpkg, shutdown, database

Whenever I'm installing a package I get the following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I've had the problem before, but now whenever I run it, it randomly shuts down my computer and haven't made any changes.. It also happens when I try to make a full update and upgrade like so:

```
sudo apt update && apt full-upgrade && apt autoremove
```

It shuts down at some point after trying to install the packages..

When running `dpkg --configure -a` it gives the following output:

```
Setting up man-db (2.8.4-3) ... 

Building database of manual pages ...
```

Then after like 10 sec or so, it shuts down and haven't made any changes.. 
I believe the shut down happens at this point as well, when running the update/upgrade command `sudo apt update && apt full-upgrade && apt autoremove`

Any idea how to fix this??

Comment: "it randomly shuts down my computer " smells like hardware failure. Ubuntu does not have a "random shutdown" feature (who would want that?) Start looking at common culprits: Overheating, dying power supply, etc.

Comment: @user535733 
It's a desktop computer. I've watched the system monitor and all 12 cores didn't reach 100% or even close to.. Neither did the GPU. 
I've ran the commands like 50 times or so today, with the same result of immediate shut down.. 
But now suddenly it works?!? I did nothing out of the ordinay, but holy dam I'm happy that it works! If you or anyone else have an idea of what the problem was please let me know!

Comment: Intermittent? The reek of defective or dying hardware is even stronger. Perhaps a loose connection, a short, etc.